# Volatile variable not updated despite unoptimized assembly

Tags: c, arm, freertos, iar

I'm working on a dual-core Cortex-R52 ARM chip, with an instance of FreeRTOS running in each core (AMP), and using ICCARM (IAR) as my compiler.

I need to ensure that CPU1 initialize some tasks, in order to pass their handler to CPU0 through the shared memory, but both cores are executed at the same time, which creates a problem in the scenario where CPU0 gets to using the supposedly passed handler, that wasn't created yet by CPU1.

A solution I tried, was creating a volatile variable **pdSTART** at a dedicated address space, which keeps CPU0 looping as long as its equal to 0:

```
#pragma location = 0x100F900C
__no_init volatile uint8_t pdSTART;

while (pdSTART == 0)
{
    vTaskDelay(10 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
}
```

As expected the generated assembly was as follows:

```
vTaskDelay(10 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    0xc3a: 0x200a         MOVS      R0, #10                 ; 0xa
    0xc3c: 0xf000 0xf93c  BL        vTaskDelay              ; 0xeb8
while (pdSTART == 0)
    0xc40: 0x7b28         LDRB      R0, [R5, #0xc]
    0xc42: 0x2800         CMP       R0, #0
    0xc44: 0xd0f9         BEQ.N     0xc3a
```

With register R5 containing the address 0x100F9000.

Using the debugger I made sure CPU0 reaches the while condition first and gets in the loop, I then made CPU1 change the value of pdSTART, which I confirmed on the memory map

```
    pdSTART:
  0x100f'900c: 0x0000'0001    DC32      VECTOR_RBLOCK$$Base
```

And yet the condition on CPU0 remains false and pdSTART is never updated, both the memory map and "Watch" window of the debugger show the variable updated.

I tried explicitly writing a read from the address of pdSTART:

```
void func(void)
{
  asm volatile ("" : : "r" (*(uint8_t *)0x100F900C));
}
```

But the generated assembly was the same as the while condition.

Is the old value of pdSTART saved into some kind of stack or cache? is there a way to forcefully update it?

Thank you.

Comment: If the memory is cached, it is very possible that this value is not being flushed before the second CPU is reading it. `volatile` won't help here, you need to handle the cache "manually" or use uncached buffers.

Comment: I see, I lack experience with handling cache, I will try to disable it on startup if possible, and see if it's the source of the problem.

Comment: If you want to ensure that @EugeneSh. see's your comment, preface your comment to him as I have done here (with a `@` symbol preceding his moniker)

Comment: Ah, thank you @ryyker, It seems there is no way now to edit the previous comment, I will make sure to do it correctly from now on.

Comment: That's okay.  He will see it (if not already) because I already flagged him in my last comment :)  (On this site, you are flagged automatically, even without the `@BowTieping` when comment is under your post.)

Comment: @ryyker Not that it is some action point for me to be aware of :P

Comment: @EugeneSh. - Understood :) - just providing a tip to new user.  (I believed comment was intended for you, even though it didn't have an ask.)

Comment: @EugeneSh. - Thank you very much! disabling the cache of CPU0 solved the problem; This should have been one of the first things I try, but manipulating cache always scared me haha. Another question if possible, should I just close the question? or post an answer myself and mark it?

Comment: @BowTieping You can post an answer yourself, if it is sufficiently informative. You can wait for someone to post another formal answer. You can delete this question all together. Or you can leave it as is, it is not bad or not useful.

Comment: BTW, disabling cache only on CPU0 might be not sufficient. If CPU1 is cached too then there is a possibility that it will read cached value instead of the one written by CPU0. Disabling the cache alltogether is probably not the best solution. You can control the cacheability of different memory pages in your MMU mapping.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - Understood; Thank you.